# Passage to limit in differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, hamilton-equations

we consider the equation 
\begin{equation}
\partial_t u (t , x) + v (t, x) \cdot \nabla u ( t, x) = \kappa
\Delta u (t , x) + F ( t, x, u (t , x) ) \qquad \mbox{in} \ \
\mathbb{R}_+ \times \mathbb{R}^d...…(0.1)
\end{equation}

with initial condition

\begin{equation}
u (0 , x) = u_0 ( x) \qquad \mbox{dans} \ \ \mathbb{R}^d ….(2)
\end{equation}
In (0.1) $ v (t, x) $ and $ F ( t, x, u ) $ are function doned and $ \kappa $ is constant strictly positive.

We denote $u^{[\kappa]}(t,x)$ the solution of the equation (0.1) with the initial condition (0.2).

We also consider the equation of transport

\begin{equation}
\partial_t u (t , x) + v (t, x) \cdot \nabla u ( t, x) =
F ( t, x, u (t , x) ) \qquad \mbox{in} \ \
\mathbb{R}_+ \times \mathbb{R}^d ,.....(0.3)
\end{equation}
who correspond to equation (0.1) in the case $ \kappa = 0 $.

We denote by $ u^{[0]} (t,x) $ the solution of the equation (0.3) with the initial condition (0.2).

I have defined a family of solution $u^{[\kappa,n]}$ of (0.1) who converge to $u^{[\kappa]}(t,x)$ when $n \to +\infty$ and a family of solutions $u^{[0,n]}(t,x)$ of (0.3) who converge to $u^{[0]}(t,x)$.

and i proved that $u^{[\kappa]}(t,x)$ converge to $u^{[0]}(t,x)$ when $\kappa \to 0$.

My question is how we proved that $\nabla u^{[\kappa]}(t,x)$ converge to $u^{[0]}(t,x)$ when $\kappa \to 0$ and $\Delta u^{[\kappa]}(t,x)$ converge to $\Delta u^{[0]}(t,x)$ when $\kappa \to 0$? To conclude that the the solutio  of  (0.1) converge to the solution to (0.3) when $\kappa \to 0$?

Thank you in advance.

Best regards

Comment: I may be misremembering, but saying $u^[0]$ is a solution to the $\kappa$ less equation ahead of time may not make sense since we don't have uniqueness for nonlinear equations necessarily.  Instead I think the point is to prove that the limit exists and converges to $\textbf{a}$ solution of (0.3). This special limit solution is called a viscosity solution, and viscosity solutions do have some form of uniqueness.

Comment: yes you're right. We can prove the uniquessess by caracteristic method. Please how we apply the method to pasing on the limit? Can you explain it please

Comment: Prove by contradiction. Suppose the limit existed and was not a solution to the viscosityless equation. Alternatively you can find the Hamiltonian for this PDE and justify the passing of the limit by the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: What happen if we suppose that lim_{\kappa \to 0} u^{[\kappa]} = u^{[0]}$ is not solution of the equation (0.3)? Please please can wrie this idea with few details in the answer? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: please give me one of the two methods you suggested in the answer so that I understand how to do it